# How to use listview to create an agenda as in outlook

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, calendar

i am working parttime on a software that is supposed to show the user the appointments for the next days and enable them to directly write a mail, letter in word or whatever by clicking a button belonging to the appointment, as one of the main features.

I am trying to build something like an outlook agenda. Meaning i have a listview which is supposed to contain elements i call appointments. 
However I am rather inexperienced in building my own Windows Forms elements, as I am doing it for the first time and even though i find information similar to the answers I am looking for I can not find an answer to these problems:

1. I want my listview to contain appointments(Objects of my class named Appointment) and resize them according to the users screensize, as well as scroll through them-meaning i want to replace the items it usually has with my appointments. In addition to that I want to filter the appointments and only show the ones that fit the criteria

so far i only created a class named AppointmentList which inherits from ListView and decided on the SQL statements to sort them

2. whenever a new appointment is created with a dialogue i want it to be created as an item of the listview and not just anywhere on the screen.

so far it just appears somewhere on the screen and has no connection to the listview

3. the appointments having the correct size.

I did set the size of the rectangle test object I made by overwriting the OnPaint method, however the size is not what it is supposed to be. It is smaller than the size i set when i check the properties of the created appointment

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics gfx = pe.Graphics;
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.Height= 69;
        rec.Width = 223;
        gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), rec);
        gfx.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0f),rec);
    }
```

[what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXAI.png)

[what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYz0r.png)
However i would like it to have little buttons as big as a mail icons and more than just a headline and a description. I wish to have the contact information in short there and if it is too long I will use tooltipps upon the mouseover action. On top of the list of appointments I want to have a filter range where the user can select the days of which he/she wants to see the appointments.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Yours sincerly

Feliza

PS: Since my old post was closed and not opened again after I edited it to make it more clear I am opening this new topic and hope that I wrote it in a way everyone can understand what I am looking for.

Comment: [A Professional Calendar/Agenda View That You Will Use](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will)

Comment: The title sounds very much too broad, but the coding problem probably is not. So I would change the title and reduce the question to the actual coding question. To get answerable we will need quite a bit more, though, like how does the class get called etc.. And maybe a screenshot of what is and what should be..

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the hint I am currently checking if it can be changed to my needs but it really fits what i look for nearly perfectly. The only question is if I can manipulate it and change a few things about it

Comment: @TaW thanks i changed the title and added pictures. I hope it is better this way.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I finally checked out the link you send me. sadly it is not perfectly what I need and given that i only work 10hours a week it would take too much time to understand the code and change it. thus my question remains unanswered as to how i can build something like this on my own

Comment: Creating something like that surely will takes a'lot of your times. So using a 3rd party component will be a good option for you based on your time limitations. Also if you decide to handle it yourself using a simpler UI, consider using a `DateTimePicker` and a `DataGridView`.